# Passing data entered from directive to controller in AngularJS

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, controller, directive

I am trying to execute inline editing in angularJS, then update data entered in Mysql table, but i am new in angular and dont know how to handle the data entered (from directive) and passing it to controller to save it in DB, so in the codes below: the variables `tid` still empty after editing .. how can i store new id  after inline editing to send them to database?

html:

```
<tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in ItemsByPage[currentPage]">
                        <td>
                            <div contentEditable="true" ng-model="tid" val='tid'>
                                {{item.id}}                                    
                            </div>

                            <button ng-click="inlineupdate()" type="button">
                                Save
                            </button>
                        </td>
 </tr>
                </tbody>
```

in controller:

```
$scope.inlineupdate = function () {
                var data = {
                    tid : $scope.val,                       
                };
               var request = $http({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "inlineupdate.php",
                    params: {
                        action: "post"
                    },
                    data: data
                });
                return( request.then( handleSuccess, handleError ) );

            };
```

and the directive:

```
myApp.directive('contenteditable', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    val : '='
                },                   
                link: function(scope, elm, ctrl) {

                    // view -> model
                    elm.bind('blur', function() {
                        scope.$apply(function() {
                            ctrl.$setViewValue(elm.html());
                        });
                    });

                    // model -> view
                    ctrl.render = function(value) {
                        elm.html(value);

                    };

                    // load init value from DOM
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(elm.html());

                    elm.bind('keydown', function(event) {
                        console.log("keydown " + event.which);
                        var esc = event.which == 27,
                            el = event.target;

                        if (esc) {
                                console.log("esc");
                                ctrl.$setViewValue(elm.html());
                                el.blur();
                                event.preventDefault();                        
                            }

                    });

                }
            };
```

and the inlineupdate.php file to update data in mysql:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include 'connect.php';
$db = new database();
$db->setDb_name('training');
$db->connect();
if(isset($_POST)){
$id = $_POST['val'];
$name = 'name';
$data =   $db->inlineupdate('user',array('id'=>$id),array('name'=>$name));
 echo json_encode($data);
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

the console fires the notice that "Undefined index: tid in inlineupdate.php file"

Comment: Pass your ID in `inlineupdate()` and update the function's definition as well

Comment: Doesn't this code ` tid : $scope.val`  mean passing ID?
How to do what you say!